# Desktop Notification requireinteraction true not working

Tags: javascript, notifications

Im having trouble with Notifications API, it all works great, permissions granted perfectly, notifications show very good in Chrome 60 and Firefox, no problem at all, this is just the case with standard notifications, when i add requireInteraction: true, the notification does not show

```
if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
                    // If it's okay let's create a notification
                    var notification = new Notification('Test', {
                      requireInteraction: true,
                      body: 'Test Body.'
                    });
                  }
                else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
                    var notification = new Notification('Test', {
                      requireInteraction: true,
                      body: 'Test Body.'
                    });
                  }
```

If i put false or delete that line, notifications works great, i checked documentation, and apparently this feature is working fine with the browsers im checking, is there something i'm missing with this?

Here's aa fiddle where you can see that it only works if its set to false or remove it
https://jsfiddle.net/b9bbzm8n/4/

appreciate the help

Comment: i think this is actually a bug. i have the same problem. it used to work and with the new chrome (in my case) it stopped